# How to do in spring boot that connects to a scheme in a database and not to the public

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, application.properties

I have a Spring Boot api that connects to a database in postgresql,In the database I have two schemes, one of my own and the public.
when inserting the table that I have in my scheme is created in the public and inserted there.
I have tried to put in the entity the name of my scheme but it gives me an error and says that it does not exist, I do not know if it is necessary to do so:

```
@Entity
@Table(  name = "rules" , schema = "eschema1")
```

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://15.98.0.65:5432/database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver


spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: I hope you are not really using the `postgres` user for your web application?

Comment: yes we are using that , Why?

Comment: Already, it is for some tests is not the definitive, now I would need this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three solutions:

1. add `?currentSchema=eschema1` to the [connection URL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters)
2. permanently change the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for that user:

   ```
   alter user postgres set search_path = 'public,eschema1';
   ```
3. Tell your obfuscation layer (=ORM) to prefix the tables with the schema you have configured. How exactly that is done, I don't know.

---

I would strongly suggest you use a different user than `postgres` - even if it's just for testing purposes.

Comment: I did the first thing and it gave me this error:
2019-12-04 09:31:08.410 ERROR 22300 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "rules" does not exist
  Position: 162
2019-12-04 09:31:08.424  INFO 22300 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Comment: I just saw that it does not work for me because when doing the from schema.Table puts the scheme without parentheses and it only works for me when it is put in parentheses, as I do that in java it is put with parentheses when doing the insert